# Does any other scripture mention Kalakrit?

Tags: parashurama, tripura-rahasyam, samvarta

Samvarta is an avaduta. Parasurama accidentally encountered Samvarta and listened to the story of a person named Kalakrit.

> He incessantly contemplated the figure of that Holy Mother Tripura,
> performing at the same time his daily tasks and the special ceremonies
> connected with Her worship and recitations. Twelve years thus passed
> in a flash. Then on a certain day while the son of Jamadagni was
> sitting at ease, he fell into a reverie. In the past, I did not
> understand even a little of what Samvarta told me when I met him on
> the way. I have also forgotten what I asked my Guru. I heard from him
> the Gospel of Tripura. But it is not clear to me what Samvarta said in
> reply to my query on creation. **He mentioned the story of Kalakrit**,
> but went no further, knowing that I was not fit for it. Even now I
> understand nothing of the workings of the universe.
>
> [[25-31, 1, Jnana Kanda, Tripura Rahasya]](https://selfdefinition.org/ramana/Tripura-Rahasya-The-Mystery-Beyond-the-Trinity.pdf#page=22)

I think this is the only place in Tripura Rahasya that has mentioned Kalakrit, and the scripture does not contain the whole conversation, which includes the story. And also, we can infer that the story of Kalakrit can be powerful and interesting as an avaduta Samvarta explained it to Parasurama. I never heard the name Kalakrit before.

Are there any other scriptures that mention the name of this Kalakrit?